# Can't select bones in Weight Paint mode

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting, select

I've tried selecting an Armature in *Pose Mode*, switched to *Object Mode*, and then *Weight Paint* mode, but it still doesn't allow me to select bones, among a plethora of other solutions. I'm not sure why, but for some reason it just doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

top menu `Edit > Lock Object Modes > uncheck`

Then you can select multiple items when in edit mode.
Set your mesh to weight paint while your rig is in pose mode.

Comment: Jeez, it's always a random checkbox somewhere.

Comment: you also need to check that the paint mask & vertex selection boxes are not highlighted next to the Weight Paint selection in the upper left (as momchilo points out below).

Answer (score 9):

You need to parent the mesh to the armature first to setup the weights, this is done with *Lock Object Modes* checked.

In *Object Mode*, select the mesh, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select armature, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to parent and choose *Armature Deform* then select any sub-option, like *With Automatic Weights*.

You should now be able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left mouse</kbd> on the bones in weight paint mode but only if you have selected the armature first, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> selected the mesh, and entered *Weight Paint mode*.

Answer (score 4):

Select armature - go in pose mod - shift + select mesh - go in weight paint - select bone with ctrl + left click.

Edit: [video with your file](https://files.catbox.moe/6suzss.mp4)

Comment: It still won't let me select a specific bone with ctrl+left click. When I try to, it just bring me out of weight paint mode into pose mode.

Comment: left click by default no?

Comment: Same problem for me as with LuckyCOINNNN.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure **neither** Paint Mask or Vertex Selection (in the upper left corner) is highlighted (so they both got to be off) and you will be able to select individual bones with Ctrl + Left click.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason of this issue found in *Edit > Preferences > Keymap*. Go to *Keymap* and select *Key-Binding* mode of search. Then type "ctrl left mouse" in the search input field. Look for the result weight paint section, here are 3 values by default. Delete the Weight Paint - ctrl left mouse line with the little x button. Save preferences, and now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> should work to bone select.

Answer (score 1):

In my blender 4.0.1 version. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Click</kbd> for select bone in weight paint mode.